# whats wrong with my code - object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to object oriented programming in JavaScript. I'm not sure what's wrong with following program:

```
function Sample() {
    var data = "one";

    var getData = function () {
        return data;
    };

    this.getter = function () {
        getData();
    };
}

var s = new Sample;

alert(s.getter()); // alerts undefined
```

The above program doesn't work as I expected it to, but the following program does:

```
function sample() {
    var data = "one";

    var getData = function () {
        return data;
    };

    this.getter = function () {
        return getData();
    };
}

var s = new Sample;

alert(s.getter()); // alerts "one"
```

Why is it so?

Comment: What is wrong with your code is the first version is just wrong (with no "return" in the getter), while the second version (which works) is written correctly. Also, I would argue it is impossible to write proper object oriented code in JavaScript. You can get close but never all the way, better just not to try.

Comment: get function return value .. you should use `return` keyword . `this.getter = function(){return getData();}` is the correct statement.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use, because your `getter` method is nor returning any value to the caller.

In your  `getter`, you are calling `getData` method which return the value of `data` but that value is not sent back the the caller of `getter`

```
this.getter = getData
```

or

```
this.getter = function () {return getData();}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first sample of code you are not returning any value - just calling the function `getData`. The return value does not 'propagate' further (is not being passed further as return value for `getter` function.

```
// Here you are just calling getData
this.getter = function () {getData();} 

// Here you are returning the value returned by getData function
this.getter = function () {return getData();}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in your code only. You are not returning in the first case. How will you get it in alert if you don't return. Your second snippet fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from first `getter` of `sample`. That's why you are getting `undefined`